# Is "WHERE foo" and "WHERE foo IS TRUE" equivalent in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I get the same counts from these:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE admin
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE admin IS TRUE
```

Are they equivalent or are there subtle or not-so-subtle differences?

Is one preferred, perhaps for cross-engine compatibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a subtle difference in the handling of NULL values [as mentioned in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html):

```
SELECT null::boolean -- null
SELECT null::boolean IS TRUE -- boolean false
SELECT null::boolean IS NOT TRUE -- boolean true
```

In short, the `IS` syntax *always* returns a boolean value, rather than propagating NULLs. This wouldn't make a difference in a `WHERE` clause, because a `NULL` condition excludes rows, but is an important difference to know.

Other than that, the main advantage is being explicit: in a complex SQL query, it might not be obvious that a particular column is a boolean, so adding the `IS TRUE` makes the intent clearer.

Users coming from systems with no boolean type might also instinctively use `WHERE admin = TRUE` (which *would* propagate `NULL`s in a context where that made a difference). The code wouldn't actually be portable to such systems, because they wouldn't recognise the "true" keyword.

Answer (score 1):

They are absolutely equivalent, because in a `WHERE` condition `FALSE` and NULL both won't pass.

There is no technical reason to prefer one or the other. I personally prefer the first, which is shorter, while I find that most other people prefer `WHERE admin = TRUE`.